# Quran Khatam as a family

Tags: reading-quran

My dad has made a separate family group chat on WhatsApp dedicated to us completing the quran collectively. There are 5 of us in the group chat and we are tasked with completing 6 chapters of the quran each and then collectively we would have completed the recitation of the quran.

We are given a timescale to complete this in too, such as a month or two and then the practice is repeated.

We are also told that this isn't the only recitation of the quran we should be doing, we should be doing our own too.

Is there anything wrong with this practice?

Comment: What should be wrong with this practice?

Comment: I have not heard or seen this practice done by the prophet or his companions, therefore I want to assure myself and my family that it doesn't fall within bid'ah.